# Converting an XElement with value into an Empty element (where XElement.IsEmpty = true)

Tags: c#, .net

I'm working with C# .Net 3.5 and trying to convert a given xml (XDocument) into an empty one (where XElement.IsEmpty would be true) containing no text values . I tried setting the XElement.Value to String.Empty but that results in `<element><element>` which isn't what i need. I needed it to be `<element />`. Can someone suggest how this can be done in .NET.

below is input example:

```
    <Envelope>
        <Body>
            <Person>
                <first>John</first>
                <last>Smith</last>
                <address>123</address>
            </Person>
        </Body>
    <Envelope>
```

expected output:

```
    <Envelope>
        <Body>
            <Person>
                <first />
                <last />
                <address />
            </Person>
        </Body>
    <Envelope>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`ReplaceWith()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement.replacewith%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) function to replace desired elements with empty elements :

```
var xml = @"<Envelope>
        <Body>
            <Person>
                <first>John</first>
                <last>Smith</last>
                <address>123</address>
            </Person>
        </Body>
    </Envelope>";
var doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
foreach (XElement propertyOfPerson in doc.XPathSelectElements("/Envelope/Body/Person/*").ToList())
{
    propertyOfPerson.ReplaceWith(new XElement(propertyOfPerson.Name.LocalName));
}
Console.WriteLine(doc.ToString());
```

Result :
[image]

Answer (score 2):

In Interest of sharing and whilst i have accepted the answer above, i actually went with the below approach and using A  XSLT to transform the XML into what i wanted, so using the below code:

```
//an XSLT which removes the values and stripes the white spaces
const string xslMarkup = "<xsl:stylesheet version=\"1.0\" xmlns:xsl=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform\"> <xsl:output method=\"xml\" omit-xml-declaration=\"yes\" indent=\"no\"/> <xsl:strip-space elements=\"*\"/> <xsl:template match=\"@* | node()\"> <xsl:copy> <xsl:apply-templates select=\"@* | node()\"/> </xsl:copy> </xsl:template> <xsl:template match=\"node()|@*\"> <xsl:copy> <xsl:apply-templates select=\"node()|@*\"/> </xsl:copy> </xsl:template><xsl:template match=\"*/text()\"/> </xsl:stylesheet>";

var transformedXml = new XDocument();
XNode xml = YOUR_XML_OBJECT_HERE;
using (var writer = transformedXml.CreateWriter())
{
    // Load the XSLT
    var xslt = new XslCompiledTransform();
    xslt.Load(XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(xslMarkup)));

    // Execute the transform and output the results to a writer.
    xslt.Transform(xml.CreateReader(), writer);
}

return transformedXml.ToString(SaveOptions.DisableFormatting);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try creating a new XElement without a value:

```
var xElement = new XElement("Envelope", new XElement("Body", new XElement("Person", "")))
```

In that manner.

Comment: Please finish the thought. As written, this does not answer the question very well.

Comment: Sorry, writing from my smartphone. Try it now